# Unable to restore the Db2 backup

Tags: db2, database-restore

I am unable to restore the Db2 backup. Getting error while executing the following line
DB2 Version : 9.7, AIX Version 5.3

**rollforward db VATAMC2 stop**

**SQL0752N  Connecting to a database is not permitted within a logical unit of
work when the CONNECT type 1 setting is in use.  SQLSTATE=0A001**

Attached are the set of commands that I executed to restore the db.
I am getting Error due to the last statement only and the rest all the statements are executed successfully.

Logs attached.
Can someone help me out with the same?

**Code which I executed:**

restore db PRODVAT user mstadmin using password from /data/db2_backupfs taken at 20160304 into VATAMC2 redirect without prompting;

set tablespace containers for 29 using (path '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs29/cont1');

set tablespace containers for 46 using (path '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs46/cont1');

set tablespace containers for 47 using (path '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs47/cont1');

set tablespace containers for 43 using (path '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs43/cont1');

set tablespace containers for 48 using (path '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs48/cont1');

set tablespace containers for 44 using (path '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs44/cont1');

set tablespace containers for 34 using (file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs34/cont1' 589824);

set tablespace containers for 35 using (file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs35/cont1' 4680192,  file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs35/cont1a' 4680192);

set tablespace containers for 36 using (file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs36/cont2' 3669984,  file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs36/cont2a' 3669984);

set tablespace containers for 37 using (file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs37/cont1' 3898624,  file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs37/cont1a' 3898624);

set tablespace containers for 38 using (file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs38/cont1' 3295788 , file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs38/cont1a' 1647892);

set tablespace containers for 39 using (file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs39/cont1' 3669976 , file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs39/cont12a' 3669976, file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs39/cont12b' 3669976, file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs39/cont13a' 3669976);

set tablespace containers for 40 using (file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs40/cont1' 5509291, file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs40/cont1a' 5509290, file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs40/cont1b' 5509290);

set tablespace containers for 41 using (file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs41/cont1' 2294656);

set tablespace containers for 42 using (file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs42/cont1' 4718592);

set tablespace containers for 45 using (file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs45/cont1' 1987872,  file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs45/cont2' 1987872);

set tablespace containers for 49 using (file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs49/cont1' 4476974,  file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs49/cont2' 4476973,  file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs49/cont3' 4476973);

set tablespace containers for 50 using (file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs50/cont1' 3744512);

set tablespace containers for 51 using (file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs51/cont1' 5639424);

set tablespace containers for 52 using (file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs52/cont1' 4132096);

set tablespace containers for 53 using (file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs53/cont1' 3932160);

set tablespace containers for 54 using (file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs54/cont1' 4469376, file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs54/cont2' 4469376, file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs54/cont3' 4469376);

set tablespace containers for 55 using (file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs55/cont1' 4194304, file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs55/cont2a' 4194304, file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs55/cont2b' 4194304, file '/data/VAT_AMC2/tbs55/cont3a' 4194304);

restore db PRODVAT continue;

rollforward db VATAMC2 stop;

**Db2 Log:**

2016-03-10-09.06.41.911428-360 E6918736A469       LEVEL: Event
PID     : 389280               TID  : 2572        PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000         DB   : VATAMC2
APPHDL  : 0-7                  APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.160310150641
AUTHID  : MSTADMIN
EDUID   : 2572                 EDUNAME: db2agent (VATAMC2) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqeLocalDatabase::FirstConnect, probe:1000
START   : DATABASE: VATAMC2  : ACTIVATED: NO

2016-03-10-09.06.41.913584-360 E6919206A481       LEVEL: Info
PID     : 389280               TID  : 2572        PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000         DB   : VATAMC2
APPHDL  : 0-7                  APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.160310150641
AUTHID  : MSTADMIN
EDUID   : 2572                 EDUNAME: db2agent (VATAMC2) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqluxGetDegreeParallelism, probe:774
DATA #1 : 
Autonomic BAR - using parallelism = 2.

2016-03-10-09.06.41.915158-360 E6919688A492       LEVEL: Info
PID     : 389280               TID  : 2572        PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000         DB   : VATAMC2
APPHDL  : 0-7                  APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.160310150641
AUTHID  : MSTADMIN
EDUID   : 2572                 EDUNAME: db2agent (VATAMC2) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqludPrintStartingMsg, probe:1338
DATA #1 : 
Starting a full database restore.
Agent EDU ID: 2572

2016-03-10-09.06.41.915354-360 E6920181A554       LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 389280               TID  : 2572        PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000         DB   : VATAMC2
APPHDL  : 0-7                  APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.160310150641
AUTHID  : MSTADMIN
EDUID   : 2572                 EDUNAME: db2agent (VATAMC2) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqluCompareDB, probe:1445
DATA #1 : Sqlcode, PD_TYPE_SQLCODE, 4 bytes
2528
DATA #2 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x07000000491947D8 : 0000 09E0                                  ....

2016-03-10-09.06.41.915502-360 E6920736A985       LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 389280               TID  : 2572        PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000         DB   : VATAMC2
APPHDL  : 0-7                  APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.160310150641
AUTHID  : MSTADMIN
EDUID   : 2572                 EDUNAME: db2agent (VATAMC2) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqluCompareDB, probe:1445
MESSAGE : SQL2540W  Restore is successful, however a warning "" was encountered 
          during Database Restore while processing in No Interrupt mode.
DATA #1 : SQLCA, PD_DB2_TYPE_SQLCA, 136 bytes
 sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: 2540   sqlerrml: 4
 sqlerrmc: 2528
 sqlerrp : sqluComp
 sqlerrd : (1) 0x00000000      (2) 0x00000000      (3) 0x00000000
           (4) 0x00000000      (5) 0x00000000      (6) 0x00000000
 sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)
           (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)        (11)
 sqlstate:

2016-03-10-09.06.41.919710-360 E6921722A520       LEVEL: Info
PID     : 389280               TID  : 2572        PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000         DB   : VATAMC2
APPHDL  : 0-7                  APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.160310150641
AUTHID  : MSTADMIN
EDUID   : 2572                 EDUNAME: db2agent (VATAMC2) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqluxGetAvailableHeapPages, probe:888
DATA #1 : 
Autonomic BAR - heap consumption.
Targetting (90%) - 112118 of 124576 pages.

2016-03-10-09.06.41.919864-360 E6922243A508       LEVEL: Info
PID     : 389280               TID  : 2572        PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000         DB   : VATAMC2
APPHDL  : 0-7                  APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.160310150641
AUTHID  : MSTADMIN
EDUID   : 2572                 EDUNAME: db2agent (VATAMC2) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqludTuneBuffers, probe:1139
DATA #1 : 
Autonomic restore - tuning enabled.
Using buffer size = 4097, number = 4.

2016-03-10-09.06.42.976640-360 I6922752A522       LEVEL: Error
PID     : 389280               TID  : 13109       PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
EDUID   : 13109                EDUNAME: db2bm.2572.0 (VATAMC2) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, buffer pool services, sqlbDMSDoContainerOp, probe:810
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x8402001E=-2080243682=SQLB_CONTAINER_NOT_ACCESSIBLE
          "Container not accessible"
DATA #1 : 
Error checking container 0 (/dsexp11/cont/tbs60/cont1) for tbsp 56.  Rc = 870F0011

2016-03-10-09.06.43.094056-360 E6923275A555       LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 389280               TID  : 2572        PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000         DB   : VATAMC2
APPHDL  : 0-7                  APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.160310150641
AUTHID  : MSTADMIN
EDUID   : 2572                 EDUNAME: db2agent (VATAMC2) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqludBMResponse, probe:310
DATA #1 : Sqlcode, PD_TYPE_SQLCODE, 4 bytes
1277
DATA #2 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x07000000491947D8 : 0000 04FD                                  ....

2016-03-10-09.06.43.094275-360 E6923831A1057      LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 389280               TID  : 2572        PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000         DB   : VATAMC2
APPHDL  : 0-7                  APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.160310150641
AUTHID  : MSTADMIN
EDUID   : 2572                 EDUNAME: db2agent (VATAMC2) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqludBMResponse, probe:310
MESSAGE : SQL1277W  A redirected restore operation is being performed.  Table 
          space configuration can now be viewed and table spaces that do not 
          use automatic storage can have their containers reconfigured.
DATA #1 : SQLCA, PD_DB2_TYPE_SQLCA, 136 bytes
 sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: 1277   sqlerrml: 0
 sqlerrmc: 
 sqlerrp : sqludBMR
 sqlerrd : (1) 0x00000000      (2) 0x00000000      (3) 0x00000000
           (4) 0x00000000      (5) 0x00000000      (6) 0x00000000
 sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)
           (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)        (11)
 sqlstate:

2016-03-10-09.06.43.883679-360 E6924889A567       LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 389280               TID  : 2572        PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000         DB   : VATAMC2
APPHDL  : 0-7                  APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.160310150641
AUTHID  : MSTADMIN
EDUID   : 2572                 EDUNAME: db2agent (VATAMC2) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqludCheckRedirectedStatus, probe:1065
DATA #1 : Sqlcode, PD_TYPE_SQLCODE, 4 bytes
1277
DATA #2 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x07000000491947D8 : 0000 04FD                                  ....

2016-03-10-09.06.43.883857-360 E6925457A1069      LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 389280               TID  : 2572        PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000         DB   : VATAMC2
APPHDL  : 0-7                  APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.160310150641
AUTHID  : MSTADMIN
EDUID   : 2572                 EDUNAME: db2agent (VATAMC2) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqludCheckRedirectedStatus, probe:1065
MESSAGE : SQL1277W  A redirected restore operation is being performed.  Table 
          space configuration can now be viewed and table spaces that do not 
          use automatic storage can have their containers reconfigured.
DATA #1 : SQLCA, PD_DB2_TYPE_SQLCA, 136 bytes
 sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: 1277   sqlerrml: 0
 sqlerrmc: 
 sqlerrp : sqludChe
 sqlerrd : (1) 0x00000000      (2) 0x00000000      (3) 0x00000000
           (4) 0x00000000      (5) 0x00000000      (6) 0x00000000
 sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)
           (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)        (11)
 sqlstate:

2016-03-10-09.06.43.884062-360 I6926527A840       LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 389280               TID  : 2572        PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000         DB   : VATAMC2
APPHDL  : 0-7                  APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.160310150641
AUTHID  : MSTADMIN
EDUID   : 2572                 EDUNAME: db2agent (VATAMC2) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqludCheckRedirectedStatus, probe:1068
DATA #1 : 
Insufficient space in tablespace DMS_TB6_TS; you must have at least 6402208
usable pages. (The "usable pages" total does not include pages used
internally by DB2, so the value specified on the SET TABLESPACE
CONTAINERS operation should be increased by one extent per container.
Based on the latest SET TABLESPACE CONTAINERS values specifed, the
tablespace should have 6402272 pages in total.)

2016-03-10-09.06.43.884818-360 I6927368A345       LEVEL: Severe
PID     : 360608               TID  : 1           PROC : db2bp
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000         DB   : VATAMC2 
APPID   : *LOCAL.db2inst1.160310150641
EDUID   : 1
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqleStartUsingDatabase, probe:2
RETCODE : ZRC=0xFFFFFD10=-752

2016-03-10-09.06.43.885281-360 I6927714A376       LEVEL: Error
PID     : 360608               TID  : 1           PROC : db2bp
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000         DB   : VATAMC2 
APPID   : *LOCAL.db2inst1.160310150641
EDUID   : 1
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, data protection services, sqlpsrllf, probe:317
MESSAGE : Rollforward failed to connect to database. sqlcode -752.

Comment: Belongs on ServerFault

Comment: Belongs on dba.stackexchange.com, not ServerFault

Comment: Should I post the question on dba stackexchange then?

Comment: You should probably read the error message first: " Insufficient space in tablespace DMS_TB6_TS".

Comment: That was a warning message...I have corrected the Table space size.. but still getting the same error except that warning is not coming... please assist..

Comment: Please close this question.. Issue got resolved... Additional Containers/Tablespaces were created by the DBA's... modified the script and everything is working fine now...